# Height of Mobile view-able area (between address bar and navigation bar)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

When viewing a web page on my mobile phone (Android default browser), there is an address bar at the top and a navigation bar at the bottom.  These bars dissapear if I start to scroll down a but appear the moment I scroll back up to the top. Other browsers have similar operations and each bar has their own sizing and behavior.

I need to be able to get the height of the **view-able** part of my website (ie, the part **between** the 2 bars).  When the bars retract or hide, I need to be able to detect the new height.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery you can get height of viewable part using

```
 $(window).height()
```

and if you are using javascript you can get height by following code

```
 window.innerHeight
```

I have tested this code with device Moto X.

Comment: I have tried a few methods.  Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqu3g45g/ The heights don't change when the address bar shows/hides.  It remains constant which means it is not picking up the address bar/nav bar heights.

Comment: I have tested this code in Moto X on chrome browser. It works. May be it has some issue with lower version of android. on which devices you testing?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S5 (latest version), i'll attach some screen shots

Comment: @Talon which browser are you using here. Chrome and default browser might give different results

Comment: Yeah, i'm using the default "internet" browser that comes with Android.  I haven't had a chance to test, been pushed onto some bug fixing on another project so that takes priority.  I will do some browser comparisons and get back to this thread.